# C# changing previously assigned values

Tags: c#, call-by-value

I have a function that gets called on a two dimensional array "a" and alters the array. However, it also alters any array that was previously assigned to "a", before even calling the function. I'm not sure if I understand why!

```
char[][] copy;

copy = a; // a is a also a two dimensional char array

DFSfunction(a); //DFSfunction alters values of a
```

So after DFSfunction is called, values of "copy" is also altered. How can I keep a copy of the original "a"?

Thank you!

Comment: Clone the array before passing it in.

Comment: do a [deep copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copying#Deep_copy) which is achieved wit h`Array.Clone` https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shallow-copy-and-deep-copy-in-c-sharp/

Comment: Technically clone does a shallow copy - but it will be sufficient for chars @phuclv.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are mutable in C# so if you change a in your example it will have an effect on copy as well, since they still have the same [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210428/are-immutable-arrays-possible-in-net#:%7E:text=The%20only%20thing%20to%20add,they%20can%2Fshould%20change%20things.&text=Further%20to%20Matt%27s%20answer%2C%20IList,allows%20add%2C%20remove%2C%20etc.)

So when you wrote

`copy = a`

`copy` is just pointing to the same `a` array.

To solve this you can use [Array.Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copy?view=net-5.0)..

In your example it can look something like this :

```
char[][] copy;
char[][] a;

Array.Copy(a, copy, a.Length);
```

You can also use [Array.Clone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.clone?view=net-5.0) :

```
var copy = (char[][])a.Clone();
```

Comment: Clone didn't work unfortunately, same thing as before was happening.

Comment: and I couldn't get Arary.Copy working, says copy has to be initialized first.

Comment: @Nila Pass in the clone to the method - don't pass in `a`.

Comment: A[] Array2 = Array.ConvertAll(Array1,a => (A)a.Clone()); - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464635/deep-copy-with-array